# How to change VBA array decimal separator?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to change VBA array decimal separator to dot. I see it as comma. I tried: `Application.DecimalSeparator="."`

But when I get the value as `MyString = matrix(2, 1)`, the decimal separator in VBA arrays maliciously persists as comma. I am not able to get rid of the pest.

Is there a way to detect which system separator for VBA arrays is used?

[image]

Comment: Change *Decimal separator* settings in File --> Options  --> Advanced (Use system separators section)

Comment: I do not want to do it. My solution as to be portable and work with any system. I would not like to force user to change settings.

Comment: Obviously when it comes to the debugger, you can probably live with it. In which specific circumstances is it intolerable to your users?

Comment: OK, in that case update your question for exact requirement.

Comment: What separator your IDE is using has no impact whatsoever on your code's portability. Notice the [Type] column: it says `Variant/Double`, which means that `3,72` is understood as a `Double` and that's all you need to know: it will be displayed as `3.72` on a system that uses a dot separator, and as `3%72` on a silly system that uses `%` as a decimal separator: the string representation of the number in the debugger has no bearing on its actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have end up with this function which does exactly what I want. Thank you all for answers, comments and hints.

```
Function GetVBAdecimalSep()
    Dim a(0) As Variant
    a(0) = 1 / 2
    GetVBAdecimalSep = Mid(a(0), 2, 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Exactly the right idea, although, personally I'd write 0.5 rather than a 1 / 2. Have an upvote!

Comment: It scares me that you think you need to care about this. You say you're worried about portability, but caring for how decimals are represented as strings is only likely to *cause* portability issues. This has all looks of an X-Y problem, and if that's the case then this is the right solution to the wrong problem, and you have a lot of headaches coming your way.

Comment: `Application.DecimalSeparator` will do this for you. It sets or returns the character used for the decimal separator as a string --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-decimalseparator-property-excel

Comment: No, guys! I have to fight with darted decimal separators to push the right string with correct numeric values to SQL Server. The reason why I want it may be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752188/split-string-into-table-given-row-delimiter-and-column-delimiter-in-sql-server

Comment: @PankajJaju no. Application.DecimalSeparator="." seems to change only the way dec sep is displayed in the cells. Not in arrays.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin - Ahh! Now I see what you are trying to achieve. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

VBA uses quite a few bits drawn from various parts of the platform to work out which decimal and thousands separator to use. `Application.DecimalSeparator` changes a few instances (mostly on the workbook); you can tweak others at the OS level, but even then though you get to a couple of cases where you *can't* change the settings.

Your best bet is to write a simple function to check which separator your platform uses based on a trial conversion of say 1.2 to a string and see what the second character ends up being. Crude but strangely beautiful.

Armed with that you can force an interchange of . and , as appropriate. Naturally then though you will have to manage all string to number parsing yourself, with some care.

**Personally though I think this is epitomises an unnecessary fight with your system settings. Therefore I would leave everything as it is; grin and bear it in other words.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it in system settings, Excel takes this kind of settings from system.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: Is there a way in VBA to detect which system separator is currently used?